# how return subarray in Lisp?

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to extract a subarray from an array? That is, a function of three arguments (the array, start index, and end index) that returns the subarray from the specified indices.  In Java, this would be something like:

```java
int[] sub(int[] arg,int begin,int end) 
{   
    int b1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arg, begin, end);
    return b1;
}
```

best regards,

Comment: "is it even possible in lisp?" sounds funny.

Comment: Do you want a copy of the original array, or new array that shares storage with the original?  E.g., if you change an element of the subarray, do you want to see it in the original too?  (The code with `copyOfRange` suggests not, but if you do, have a look into the *displaced-* arguments to [**make-array**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SUBSEQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subseq.htm#subseq) works for sequences, thus also for vectors (one-dimensional arrays) and it returns a new vector.

```
CL-USER 14 > (subseq #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 3 6)
#(3 4 5)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i dont need a library function , i need to implement it. :)

Comment: Why do you need to implement it??